# UK Multiple entry visitor visa

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, multiple-entry

I am from India and I have valid multiple entry visa valid till September 2015. I travelled to UK and stayed for a month and came back to India. Can I again travel to UK on the same visa and stay till the valid date?

Comment: Please use the green button to accept DJClayworth's answer. It is a great answer and should be accepted.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

A multiple entry visa means you can visit multiple times. Unless there is something written on your visa restricting the number of times you can visit, you can come back and visit as many times as you like until the visa expires.